# How do I create a Yes and No dialog for the function Del_img

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, submit

I've tried with JavaScript in so many ways but I can't figure this one out, I really don't know what to do here. I just want a confirm box for this control/action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Del_img", "Home", new { Name = @item.Url }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

Regards

Comment: why didn't you specify attributes like id or name or class..

Comment: I'm sorry. I've been working with MVC only for a few weeks so I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send form, you can use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Del_img", "Home", new { Name = @item.Url, @id="myForm" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick ="ConfirmDelete()" />
}

<script>
    function ConfirmDelete() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to send delete form?")) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or, generally, if you want to send any parameter to delete action:

```
<img src="..." alt="image" onclick ="ConfirmDelete(@Model.Id)"   />
```

This will send `id` to action for deleting:

```
<script>
    function ConfirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this?")) {
            document.location.href = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Controller")/' + id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And action:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
     //delete object by id
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button with id or name attributes in markup(.cshtml)

In Javascript or jquery you can add the confirmation dialog box

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='delete']").click(function() {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete?');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. Right after I asked a the question I found the solution, similar to what *Jhoon Bey* showed.

But I need all your responses further on for the project I'm working on. Thank you all for contributing.

Regards